# What experiments have been done so far to measure that the speed of light is the same in all reference frames, even with relative velocity?

Tags: special-relativity, experimental-physics, reference-frames, speed-of-light, inertial-frames

What experiments have been done so far to measure that the speed of light is the same in all reference frames with relative velocity between them, and that it is *independent of the velocity of the source*?

I know about Michelson-Morley, but that didn't really measure the speed of light from reference frames with velocity relative to the source, it just measured whether the speed of light is the same in all directions or not.

Comment: The Michelson-Morely measured speed of light from different relative velocity. remember that the earth moves

Comment: And since the original Michelson-Morley experiment, similar experiments have been performed with steadily increasing precision. Wikipedia has a useful summary (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment#Subsequent_experiments)

Comment: But in Mechelson-Morley all reference frames were also moving with the earth. What that measured was velocity relative to the ether, because it was considered that ether was fixed and that the movement of the earth means that the surface has velocity relative to it. But there was no relative velocity between the source and the reference frame from which it was measured,

Answer (score 2):

My favorite source for these kinds of questions is here:
http://www.edu-observatory.org/physics-faq/Relativity/SR/experiments.html

In particular, you are interested in section 3.3 Tests of Light Speed from Moving Sources.

My favorite in this section is K. Brecher, “Is the Speed of Light Independent of the Velocity of the Source?”, Phys. Rev. Lett. 39 1051–1054, 1236 (1977). This experiment used systems of binary pulsars to determine that the speed of light from the forward moving and backward moving pulsars differed by no more than 2 parts per billion. Basically, if c depends on the speed of the source then it is possible that you can get multiple images of a pulsar as it cycles between forward and backward travel.

There are other experiments in the lab which are also worth looking at, but that one is my favorite.

Comment: great source. About the experiment of K.breacher, I think multiple images would only happen if the speeds were faster than light, which is not possible according to relativity

Comment: @Neelim No. The number of images depends on the distance as well as the speed. For larger distances you can get multiple images with slower velocities. For astronomical distances normal orbital velocities are sufficient.

Comment: doesn't that break causality from the reference frame of the observer?

Comment: It would be a violation of relativity so it would indeed break the relativistic idea of causality. It would not break the Newtonian idea of causality. But it is experimentally falsified so it doesn't really matter. Anyway, I will remind you, as always, that comments are for improving the answer. Not for discussion or follow-up questions. I will again recommend that you go to a site which encourages discussion, like physicsforums.com

Comment: Ok. but anyway this was a general question. also isn't it relativity that suggests the multiple images? so do we actually see multiple images in observations?

Comment: @Neelim no, relativity does not suggest multiple images in this circumstance. That is what is meant by “It would be a violation of relativity” and “if c depends on the speed of the source” (in relativity c does not depend on the speed of the source). Such an observation would disprove relativity. 

You really should consider a discussion forum. There is nothing wrong with going to a site that fits your personal style better. You clearly strongly prefer discussion to straight Q&A. I have yet to see you not want to dive into a big discussion.